# Statuscode 406 (Not Acceptable) in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

REST services should provide content negotiation. This means that clients send an Accept header that contains the desired content type of the response. If the service does not support this media type, it should respond with status code 406 (Not Acceptable).

I try to map this behavior to ASP.NET Core. ASP.NET core returns a JSON document, if it doesn't recognize the media type in the Accept header. In previous versions of the framework the behavior described above could be achieved by adding a special output formatter to the configuration:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services) {
  services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.OutputFormatters.Insert(0, new HttpNotAcceptableOutputFormatter());
  });
}
```

Unfortunately, `HttpNotAcceptableOutputFormatter` was removed from the ASP.NET Core framework after RC1. Is there any replacement for this class in the current version of the framework?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In such cases, it’s a good idea to find the commit that removed the functionality, to see what it likely got replaced with. In this case, `HttpNotAcceptableOutputFormatter`  was removed with [this commit](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commit/5a3875ea72f14cec70c22f842f17d55478729626) to fix [issue #4612](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/4612):

> Alter content negotiation algorithm so that it can be configured (via MvcOptions) to always respect an explicit Accept header.

What it was replaced with is [`MvcOptions.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.mvcoptions.returnhttpnotacceptable?view=aspnetcore-6.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-mvcoptions-returnhttpnotacceptable), which is a setting on the `MvcOptions` that you configure when adding MVC with [`AddMvc`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addmvc?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

So your code should become like this:

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
});
```

Comment: How on earth did you find that?!

Comment: @Mardoxx Looked in the RC2 branch and [found the file](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/1.0.0-rc2/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters/HttpNotAcceptableOutputFormatter.cs) using the file search (keyboard shortcut: T). That told me where the file was originally located. Then I went to the [folder’s history on the dev branch](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/commits/dev/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Core/Formatters) and did a “binary search” using the GitHub UI to find the commit that removed the file.

Answer (score 35):

I had this before:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();
}
```

Then I change it to `AddMvcCore()` instead of `AddMvc()`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvcCore();
}
```

Finally I had that issue with the Response 406 so what I did was to add `.AddJsonFormatters()` to `services.AddMVCCore()` and my API worked again.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   services.AddMvcCore()
        .AddJsonFormatters();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You add this to the `ConfigureService` method in the `Startup` class.

```
services.AddMvc(options =>
{
    options.ReturnHttpNotAcceptable = true;
    // If you need to add support for XML
    // options.OutputFormatters.Add(new XmlDataContractSerializerOutputFormatter());
});
```

Answer (score 0):

None of the above answer worked for me , finally this worked

Adding  the following line in ConfigureServices of Startup.cs

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
 {
        services.AddMvcCore().AddJsonFormatters().AddApiExplorer();
 }
```